# Is there a way to show more darker when you press button using TouchableOpacity?

Tags: react-native

I want the button to look more darker when pressed.

I thought I could assign more than 1 to activeOpacity. but it's not working.

Do you have any other way to do like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code of what you tried and have a look at this page:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `TouchableHighlight` that darkens when touched, the opposite of `TouchableOpacity`. Take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight).